# OpticalMarginAlignment like function in WP8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

With WP8.1 for Universal Apps (XAML) a new property called OpticalMarginAlignment was introduced for the TextBlock control. It basically trims to the leftmost stroke of the first character and the rightmost stroke of the last character on a line. With this I can perfectly align text on a vertical line.

I searched the WP8.1 for Silverlight reference but couldn't find anything comparable. Is there such option or is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Workaround = negative margin on the side(s) like `Margin="-2,0,0,0"`

Comment: Depending on the first character the gap is different. For some characters it is 2px, for others it is 0px.